# Why recursion behave differently in the two examples?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I have two examples of recursion, one calculate the sum of all elements of the array and the second return the count, both examples behave differently and i can't relate!

First Example:

```js
const sum = (list) => {
  if (list.length === 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  return list[0] + sum(list.slice(1));
};

console.log(sum([1, 2, 3, 4])); // 10
```

The second:

```js
const count = (list) => {
  if (list.length === 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  return 1 + count(list.slice(1));
};

console.log(count([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // 6
```

Why the first recursion go through all array elements adding every element while the other added 1 to each element then returned just the final value?? i assumed it would do the same and the difference would be just adding 1 to the sum!!

Comment: sum vs count ...?

Comment: One sums the values of the array, the other countes them. I'm not sure why you expect the two to be the same.

Comment: In the first example `list[0]` is added to the sum of all other elements in your list. In the second example `1` is added to the count of the rest of the list. `list[0]` takes the first element in the array passed into the function and adds it with the return value of further calling `sum`.

Comment: The first does `list[N - 1] + list[N - 2] + ... + list[N - N] + 0` (N being the number of elements) while the second one does `1 + 1 + ... + 1 + 0`

Comment: To maybe clarify things a bit, say you have a list of numbers. When I ask you to *sum* those, it means adding all values and giving me back the total value. When I ask you to *count* the numbers, I'm not interested in the meaning of the numbers, I simply want to know how many numbers there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursion is the same.

It visits all elements of the array and returns zero if no element is available.

For each element, it returns either the item for summing or one for counting.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `return 1 + count(list.slice(1));` in the count function. It would just ignore the 1st element in the list you pass recursively to the function and always use 1. Versus the sum function does consider that element. That effectively returns the count of times the function has been called which is 6

Answer (score 1):

1st - sum, 2nd - count,
If you wish them to do the same thing you should use only one of them.

Comment: My meaning was that you did two different things, list[index] is like a variable so every time you add to the previous value and in the count, you count the length of your list.